# Attributing values of length x*n to a list of headers length n in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have created myself the following question:

For a list of headers with length n, and another list of values length n*x, where x would be the number of values under each header,
How can I create a dictionary where each header corresponds to x data values?

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
headers = ['a','b','c'] # n = 3
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] # length = 9, so x = len(data)/n = 3 (each header has 3 values)

dictionary = {}
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
{'a': [1,4,7], 'b': [2,5,8], 'c': [3,6,9]}
```

I will be using a set of data with n = 12, x = 30 (so each column of the table of 12 headers has 30 values.)

To tackle my example I have written the following code:

```
n = len(headers)
for header in headers:
    dictionary[header] = []

for num in range(0,n):
    subList = [data[num+0*n],data[num+1*n],data[num+2*n]]
    print(num,subList)
    dictionary[headers[num]] = subList

print(dictionary)
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I am still having to add the "1 * n" or "2 * n" manually, which is unreasonable for larger n. the number is associated to the element of the list going into the dictionary (so element 0 in list = 0 * n, element 1 in list = 1 * n etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate though the list `data`, `x` times and add `data[num+i*n]` to `subList`. So you would want your definition of `subList` to be as follows:

```
subList = []
for i in range(0,x):
    subList+=[data[num+i*n]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and sorry for the late reply- Next time I should not have programmed so late in the night as this was the first thing I did in the morning! I realised that in my code I had to repeat x times and then append to the subList instead of coding the subList in manually. Out of curiosity, do you know of any external modules which can help with this sort of thing - essentially making a table out of two lists.

Comment: You could use the ```numpy``` library, and reshape the list to be 2 dimensional.